# What is a good apporach to achieve exact time-dependent sequential execution?

Tags: java, android

I am writing an application which listens to various sensors. It listens to them in recording sessions and each session includes listening to various lines at different durations (with offsets). When the recording session ends, the whole data is packed into a `RecordingSession` object and sent to the server.

There is always an interval between the recording sessions:

```
####### RecordingSession 1 ########                  ####### RecordingSession 2 ########
#|********* Line 1 **************|#                  #|********* Line 1 **************|#
#        |********* Line 2 ******|#  ** interval **  #         |******** Line 2 ******|#   ...
#                |**** Line 3 ***|#                  #                |**** Line 3 ***|#
###################################                  ###################################
```

I know I could use Java's `Timer` and then schedule `TimerTasks` for various durations with an offset. Three TimerTasks for the `Lines` and one to store the `RecordingSession` and create a new one.

Now my problem is, that it should be possible to set the interval between the recording sessions to 0 (as in the listing below). I expect, that the `Timer` even though I would set the correct times will not guarantee the perfect timed execution of each timed task. Each `Line` has a listener that registers and unregisters to the data stream of the line (each of them would have TimerTask). Now what could happen is, that if I implement it with `TimerTasks`, that it might happen that I register a listener before I unregistered it and then the unergistering would cause that no data is recorded in the next RecordingSession.

```
####### RecordingSession 1 ############### RecordingSession 2 ########
#|********* Line 1 **************|##|********* Line 1 **************|#
#         |******** Line 2 ******|##         |******** Line 2 ******|#   ...
#                |**** Line 3 ***|##                |**** Line 3 ***|#
######################################################################
```

Is there a better approach to solve this problem than with (nested) TimerTasks and Threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i went with `TimerTasks` and scheduling. Every time a line stops it notifies the recording session and as soon as there aren't any active lines anymore (which should happen to all lines about the same moment) I reschedule a `RecordingSession`.